# opentsdb api query pagination

Tags: opentsdb

I am using OpenTSDB for my time series data.

I have a use-case on the front end in which a user can fetch data from OpenTSDB between specific dates:

```
http://localhost:5000/api/query?start=2014/06/04%2020:30&end=2014/09/18%2000:00&m=sum:cpu_system
```

My problem is that the returned data is too large. Like, thousand of records if I fetch data for an interval of more than one day. The service call than takes a couple of minutes which is giving a bad user experience on front end.

I want to apply pagination on the service call so that it will take less time.

The [`/api/query` documentation](http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/api_http/query/index.html) does not have any mention of pagination. The [`/api/search` documentation](http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/api_http/search/index.html) does offer pagination, but does not have any mention of time ranges.

How can I query over a time range with pagination?

Comment: are you using curl ? what is the exact format for query. I am trying to do the same was able to insert but not query ? Can you give me the exact query format

Comment: I am doing the query through node js request module.

Answer (score 1):

There is no native pagination support in queries, but you can always emulate it by splitting your time range in multiple queries, so that, for example, you only ask for a day for each query.
Another solution that may be feasible in some cases, is to ask OpenTSDB to downsample the data. This way it will return a lot less data points, and your application will have less data to download and process.